# Avoid overlapping of google map marker using clustering

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, overlapping

There are thousands of data that I want to add on google map using clustering.

**Problem**

> It is possible that multiple records may have same latitude and longitude so I want to add those marker in such a way that it doesn't overlap one another. They can be close to each other but not overlapped.

So I have went through the google place api documentation and even googled or the various articles but I didn't found a solution that solves this issue.

Setting pin on map:-

```
- (void)setPinsToMap {
  [self.mapGoogle clear];

  for (int i=0; i<arrUsers.count; i++) {

    ClassUser *cls =[arrUsers objectAtIndex:i];

    double lat;
    double long1;

   //Here, what to do with the location coordinates?
    lat = [cls.strLat doubleValue];
    long1 = [cls.strLong doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"\n------------------\nname = %@ lat = %@,  lng = %@\n---------------\n", cls.strUserName, cls.strLat, cls.strLong);

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    id<GMUClusterItem> item = [[POIItem1 alloc] initWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long1) name:name];
    [_clusterManager addItem:item];

    [_clusterManager cluster];

 }
}
```

Could any one suggest a way to get this fixed. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your question. The title says ```using clustering``` but in the description you say that you want the pins to be positioned in such a way that they don't overlap. So which one is it ?

Comment: I'm using google clustering and also showing marker on map. Since there are thousand of data that I need to show on map, I used clustering but when I tap on cluster icon on map it shows the marker on map. Some marker are overlapped b'coz of the same location coordinates. So how to avoid that?